# ServiceStack Custom Registration Validator Issue

Tags: servicestack

I want to override the default Registration validator that is enabled when the Registration feature is added.
I have added my own CustomRegistrationValidator as per the ServiceStack documentation (basic rules for now, to be expanded later):

```
public class CustomRegistrationValidator : RegistrationValidator
    {
        public CustomRegistrationValidator()
        {
            RuleSet(ApplyTo.Post, () =>
            {
                RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty();
                RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotEmpty();
                RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty();
                RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotEmpty();
            });
        }
    }
```

I have overridden the default registration validator in my Configure method as per the following snippet:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new AuthUserSession(),
                  new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider(),
                  new CredentialsAuthProvider()
                }));

            Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
            Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());

            RegisterAs<CustomRegistrationValidator, IValidator<Register>>();
            container.RegisterValidators(typeof(AppHost).Assembly);
```

However, the validator never appears to execute, thus I can register new users with invalid details.

I am using the latest version of ServiceStack V4.0.22

Is this a major ServiceStack bug or is this feature no longer available with the latest version of ServiceStack?

Thank you in advance for any help with this.

Regards
John

Comment: ServiceStack Version 4.0.35 (Jan 2015) still has the Custom Registration Validator bug! (See text above) Is there a fix or workaround for this? *** URGENT FIX NEEDED ***

Comment: A workaround is registering the custom validator after initialization is finished (see my answer). Have you registered this as an issue with ServiceStack?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this is still a bug in v4.0.35. This is how I got around it...

1. Create a custom registration validation class which implements **AbstractValidator<Register>** and add your own fluent validation rules (I copied the rules from the SS source)

   ```
   public class CustomRegistrationValidator : AbstractValidator<Register>
   {
       public IAuthRepository UserAuthRepo { get; set; }
       public CustomRegistrationValidator()
       {
           RuleSet(ApplyTo.Post, () =>
           {
               RuleFor(x => x.UserName).NotEmpty().When(x => x.Email.IsNullOrEmpty());
               RuleFor(x => x.UserName)
               .Must(x => UserAuthRepo.GetUserAuthByUserName(x) == null)
               .WithErrorCode("AlreadyExists")
               .WithMessage("UserName already exists")
               .When(x => !x.UserName.IsNullOrEmpty());
               RuleFor(x => x.Email)
               .Must(x => x.IsNullOrEmpty() || UserAuthRepo.GetUserAuthByUserName(x) == null)
               .WithErrorCode("AlreadyExists")
               .WithMessage("Email already exists")
               .When(x => !x.Email.IsNullOrEmpty());

               RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty();
               RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotEmpty();
               RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty();
               RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotEmpty();
               // add your own rules here...
       });

       RuleSet(
           ApplyTo.Put,
           () =>
           {
               RuleFor(x => x.UserName).NotEmpty();
               RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty();
               // add your own rules here...
           });
   }
   ```

   }
2. Create a CustomRegistrationFeature class which implements IPlugin (again I just copied the SS source and changed the IoC registration to the CustomRegistrationValidator class)

   ```
   public class CustomRegistrationFeature : IPlugin {
       public string AtRestPath { get; set; }

       public CustomRegistrationFeature()
       {
           this.AtRestPath = "/register";
       }

       public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
       {
           appHost.RegisterService<RegisterService>(AtRestPath);
           appHost.RegisterAs<CustomRegistrationValidator, IValidator<Register>>();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Replace the RegistrationFeature registration in the App.Host with the new CustomRegistrationFeature we just created.

   ```
   Plugins.Add(new CustomRegistrationFeature());
   ```

I don't know why this works as I am just doing the same or similar thing to what's already there, but it does. It also allows me to add in more validation rules (which is why I needed to do this).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure that this is a bug, but it might be. Anyway, the reason that the custom validator isn't used, is that the `Register()` method of `RegistrationFeature` isn't called until after the `Configure()` method has been run, thus overriding the registration of `CustomRegistrationValidator`.

The simplest solution is registering the custom validator *after* the `Register()` method has been run:

```
public override void OnAfterInit()
{
    base.OnAfterInit();

    RegisterAs<CustomRegistrationValidator, IValidator<Register>>();            
}
```